# Inject object into dynamically created component constructor

Tags: angular, angular7

I have an Angular 7 component:

```
export class HelloComponent {
  constructor(private data: any) {}
}
```

And I am creating it dynamically using `ComponentFactoryResolver`:

```
private create(data: any) {

  var componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver
    .resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent)
    .create(this.injector);

  this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);

  var element = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

}
```

How to inject `data` object in HelloComponent constructor?

Comment: HelloComponent is a class so.. have you tried

`const hello = new HelloComponent(data);`

and then `.resolveComponentFactory(hello)`. Not sure if this would work but it makes a hella lotta sense to me

Comment: This https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#resolving-components may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use custom injector for that

```
const injector: Injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(
[{
     provide: 'config', useValue: { 
     value: 'Any value or object here'}
}]);
```

and in your component use this

```
export class HelloComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('config') private data: any) {}
}
```